# Tkinter new window does not appear until the function is finished

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a long process to do and I want to notify the user to wait during the time of execution.
It looks like this:

```
class MainWindows(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Nmap Database")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.resizable(True, True)
        self.create_widgets()
    ....

   def refresh(self) :
      self.openWindows()
      long_operation()

   def openWindows(self):
      window = WaitingWindows(self)
      window.grab_set()

class WaitingWindows(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("Scan")
        self.geometry("100x50")
        self.resizable(True, True)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Scanning... Please wait")
        self.label.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True)
```

But the windows appear at the end of the execution of 'long_operation()'.

Ps: I will add something to notify that the operation have finished.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to use `update_idletasks()` before calling your `long_operation()` ?

Comment: No, how should I use it? I dont really understand the documentation about the method.

Comment: `def refresh(self)` needs to be inside a class.

Comment: I didn't show it. But it's already in my ```MainWindows()``` class

Comment: How is `refresh` called?

Comment: In a button :  ```ttk.Button(... command=self.refresh)```